# Ajax post request can't get data with express router

Tags: ajax, express, post

I'm using  `express.Router()` to manage my routes.
then using  **Ajax post** request send some data to it. but I can't get the data.

ajax code :

```
        $.ajax({
            url: '/custom',
            type: 'POST',
            contentType: 'application/json; charset-utf-8',
            dataType: 'json',
            processData: false,
            data: JSON.stringify({ "key": "values" }),
            success: function(data) {
                console.log(data.toString());
            }
        })
```

express code:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();    
router.post('/custom',  function(req, res) {
        console.log(req.body);
        console.log(req.params);
        console.log(req.query);

        res.write(JSON.stringify());
        res.end();
});
```

but all the logs are empty.

Comment: can you give more code for express side??

Comment: in this file my whole code is almost this. app is defined in a separate file.
The express works when I test it with **Postman** or other routes that data is empty but in this link I need request data and it doesn't work.

Comment: Did you add **body-parser** for parsing post data? req.params and req.query should be empty and thats okay, but req.body has to be { key: values }. If not, it means that Express cannot parse body

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is because the content-type header in your ajax is malformed. 
Instead of
`contentType: 'application/json; charset-utf-8'` it should be `contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8'`.

Assuming you are using the bodyParser.json() middleware, this would cause the body to not be parsed, which would print an empty body. When you sent the requests with Postman the proper headers were sent, which is why it worked there but not from the ajax request.